# Chrome is caching even with HTTP no-cache headers

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, cache-control

I am trying to serve a PHP file output with HTTP Headers configured so the content will NOT be served from cache in Chrome.

If I go to Dev tools (in Chrome), and mark the "Disable cache" option, then it works.

But I don't want to depend on that, I hope I can setup HTTP headers in a way I can force Chrome to reload the page everytime.

Here's a screenshot of my current attempt, please note the red marks.

[image: HTTP headers]

Could you please provide good documentation or which headers I must declare for this ?

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

So I found this other reply too: [Chrome caching like a mad browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576468/chrome-caching-like-a-mad-browser), but since I recall being told that Chrome needs special headers for `Cache-Control`, I will keep this question.

Comment: If this is an ajax request, a hack is to pass a query parameter that uses the date/time in seconds.  That way it changes with every request and the browser can't cache it.

Comment: Exactly what I just coded, will test.

Comment: It worked =) Thank you, please formalize the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Web browsers can cache AJAX requests with the same request parameters.  In order to work around this problem, use a query string that changes.  One example would be to use the date in seconds as a query parameter.