# Browser loads response from cache although no-cache header is set

Tags: browser, cache-control

I'm working on a web app and I'm having the following problem:

- When I go on some page my server sends a response with *cache-control: no-cache* header.
- Then I do some changes (graphql mutations) on that page.
- When I go to an other page and then click browser back then my browser reads the outdated "response" from the disk cache instead of sending a request to the server to get the change data.

[browser loads response from cache although no-cache header is set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcQut.png)

I wondering if there is something missing in my headers telling the browser to not use the disk cache?

Some info:
The browser does not send a request to my server. (So it is not cached somewhere else.)
It is not the back-forward cache. (There is already some logic handling the bfcache.)
I can reproduce it in all my browsers. (e.g. Firefox, Chrome, ...)
When I disable the disk cache in the Firefox settings then it is working correctly. (Now, the bfcache kicks in.)

I also found the following thread. Is there a better solution?
[Chrome is caching even with HTTP no-cache headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220998/chrome-is-caching-even-with-http-no-cache-headers)